# How can I remove or disable eosio development key and assign permission for another account as super users

Tags: security

Because it's for security reasons...It seem like disable Administrator on Windows Server. Please advise, Thank you.

Comment: Means you want to change your owner key..?

Comment: I mean that eosio development key (5KQwrPbwdL6PhXujxW37FSSQZ1JiwsST4cqQzDeyXtP79zkvFD3) is well known to everyone. How can I remove or disable it.

Comment: You want to change your primary key(as you said eosio development key), yes you can do that. You have to change both owner and active private key if there any security issues.

Comment: Do you want to change key or accout permission ?

Comment: How to change config.ini file in .local/share/eosio/nodeos/config/config.ini I changed "signature provider" line with new key pair but its not working. I must load 5KQwrPbwdL6PhXujxW37FSSQZ1JiwsST4cqQzDeyXtP79zkvFD3 otherwise it won't work. So please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the config file or give your key when boot via **--private-key** like this:

```
nodeos -e -p eosio --private-key '["EOS6crW7G4Cyzyh38UmS5xrhV7LcF1bLuhHtxuhDgCUpyabG9dFgn", "5JYpn7fG3LqN3Wwo8aT6uupG5eNqRux7wHrjwqPC8HqqZByzCxr"]'
```